# Finding the first vertex in a recursively growing graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, algorithms, random-graphs

I have an undirected graph which grew according to a recursive algorithm, i.e., it started with a single vertex and then, one after another, new vertices arrived and connected to existing ones.

Now, I'm given the graph with, say, $n$ vertices. I would like to determine (efficiently) which vertex was the first one. How can I do so?

I am already aware of an algorithm by Shah & Zaman (2011) from [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5961801). However in this paper, they assume that the graph of interest (in their case the rumor graph) is actually a tree. In my situation, this does *not* necessarily have to be true.

Comment: Suppose that a second vertex comes along and connects to the first vertex. How can you determine which of the two was first?

Comment: potentially relevant paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.6821

Comment: @MishaLavrov In this case, I believe that no estimator can determine which of the two is the actual root vertex, since in the graph with two vertices, both are completely symmetric.